# python> How to execute my script in venv(created on window) on linux(VM)?

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, python-venv

Please help me. I have spent so many times for it but still don't know why.
First of all, I would like you to know that I am really new to programming and don't know well about basics.
Also sorry for my english which probably confuses you all.

I have created the venv on Pycharm (Windows 10, python 2.7 installed).
And my workspace is located on VM (Linux Centos6.1, python 2.6 by default)
I access my vm by Samba interface.

When I created venv and executed my script, I saw console said that it exceucted python.exe(2.7 version) on my venv.
So I thought, if I would move to the whole venv directory to my vm linux ,
I could run my scripts by python2.7.

But when I treid it on another VM CentOS 5.11, the result was

```
$> source myvenv/Scripts/activate
[venv]$> ./myscript 
./hello.py: line 1: import: command not found
./hello.py: line 2: import: command not found
./hello.py: line 3: import: command not found
: command not found 
: command not found 
./hello.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `'imported all successfully.''
./hello.py: line 6: `print('imported all successfully.')'
```

So I figured out it was still using python2.4 (defualt of centos5.11).
Then I googoled and tried some solutions, one of those was to change my VIRTUAL_ENV variable since it was created on Windows10.

```
vi myvenv/Script/activate
VIRTUAL_ENV="$(if [ "$OSTYPE" "==" "cygwin" ]; then cygpath -u 
'${myWindowsVenvPath}'; else echo 
'${myLinuxVenvPath}'; fi;)"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

but still doesn't work..
(Tried shebang #!/myvenv/Scripts/python in my script as well)

I guess Probably I don't understand vevn concept well.
Did I try worng? If there is any suggestion to solve it, or I have apporoached wrong, please let me know.

Thank in advance for your opinion.

revision >
my script is just for checking if the third-party modules could be imported.
(before I move to my whole script to around venv)
so it is like this below,

```
import pandas
print('it's working') --> to check if python2.7 is running since it has the different syntax for print function.
```

Comment: Can you show us what's inside this `myscript` you're running?

Comment: @yorodm I updated it in my article!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason myself.
What I got until now is the binary file :python.exe is subordinative to operating system. 
So I made venv on linux again, then it seems to work on the diffrecnt version of linux, which means the upper version of python can be excuted in venv (prerequsite: it needs libpython2.6.so as well)
still remains alot of shared libraries issue...so the conclusion is that I have approached totally wrong.